# HIve - Create Table as - error while creating parquet table from existing table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I created a Parquet table(orders_parquet) from existing table(orders) with CTAS as below :

```
CREATE TABLE orders_parquet
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
AS SELECT * FROM orders;
```

It is loading with below

```
Query ID = jonnavithulasivakrishna_20171105234912_e608ac1f-a10b-435e-8307-92747fb5c37d
Total jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Can't load log handler "java.util.logging.FileHandler"
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/parquet-3.log (Permission denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/parquet-3.log (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
        at java.util.logging.FileHandler.open(FileHandler.java:210)
        at java.util.logging.FileHandler.rotate(FileHandler.java:661)
        at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:538)
        at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:263)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at
```

But the table is loaded with data.Could you please help why the error is coming?

Comment: Just recheck the permission to /tmp/parquet-3.log file or /tmp folder.Looks like the user doesnt have permission

Comment: I have both read and write permission for parquet-3.log 
 file.jonnavithulasivakrishna@gw01 tmp]$ ls -ltr parquet-3.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 2832 students 106066 Oct 27 13:51 parquet-3.log

Answer (score 0):

Hive need write permission in /tmp location to log information. In your case hive don't have write permission to /tmp/parquet-3.log. Give write permission to given file as *`chmod 777 /tmp/parquet-3.log`*